# What should be the order of priority in Missing Values, and Outliers treatment?

Tags: outliers, data-preprocessing, missing-data

Outliers impact Missing Values.  And some times Imputed Values are also in Outliers.

If the data set has lots of outliers for a numerical variable with few missing values.  Should the outlier treatment be done prior to missing value treatment?